# Auto adjust the height of a FancyBox pop up when the content changes?

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

When user clicks on the options then fancybox pops up having all the options.and when user clicks on any of  the  listed option,then content related to that option apperes on the same  pop up  but the fancybox pop up never strechtes(auto adjusting the height and width) around the new div content.Plz help

```
<div class="modelbox" id="#options">Options</div>   //when user clicks here a fance box appeares with few options,say three.


   <div style="display:none" id="options">
    <p onclick="$("#option1div").show()" >option 1</p>        //when user clicks anyone one of these option.then the belov div opens on the fancy form. **problem is that.div opens but with the scrollbars and hight of the fancebox pop up form neve adjusted acorting to the new div content. help plz**
    <p onclick="$("#option2div").show()">option 2</p>
   <p onclick="$("#option3div").show()">option 3</p>
   <div>


    <div style="display:none" id="option1div"> large data here</div>
    <div style="display:none" id="option2div"> large data here</div>
    <div style="display:none" id="option3div"> large data here</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms, it would be better to bind fancybox to a link `<a>` like :

```
<a class="modelbox" href="#options">Options</a>
```

... in this way we could pass the `href` of the inline content without overusing javascript. Also notice that `id="#options"` is incorrect .... the `hash` in `#options` is used to refer to `id="options"` (inside the `href` for instance) but is not part of the `ID`'s name.

Secondly, if you want fancybox to adjust the `height` and `width`, then you would need to set, at least, some `width` to your hidden content (normally the `height` will be auto calculated) like :

```
<div style="display:none; width: 320px" id="option1div"> large data here</div>
<div style="display:none; width: 320px" id="option2div"> large data here</div>
<div style="display:none; width: 320px" id="option3div"> large data here</div>
```

Then your fancybox custom script should have (at least) the option `fitToView` set to `false`, otherwise fancybox will always display scrollbars when the content is longer than the `height` of the viewport like :

```
$(".modelbox").fancybox({
    fitToView: false
});
```

Last, in order to adjust the size of fancybox to the new visible content, you need to use the API method `$.fancybox.update()` within your `onclick` attribute like :

```
   <div style="display:none" id="options">
    <p onclick='$("#option1div").show(); $.fancybox.update();'>option 1</p>
    <p onclick='$("#option2div").show(); $.fancybox.update();'>option 2</p>
    <p onclick='$("#option3div").show(); $.fancybox.update();'>option 3</p>
   <div>
```

See **[working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d6TqE/)**

**NOTE** : this solution is for fancybox v2.1.3+

Comment: thank you so much.it solved the problem.but one problem is more.if once fancybox is clicked,ns option din is opened.after closing this div,and reclicking the fancybox,the previous opened div appeares insted of showing only three options.If I refresh the page then it works fine.Plz help

Comment: @AanaSaeed : you could hide the `div` again using the callback `afterClose` .... see  **http://jsfiddle.net/d6TqE/3/**